# finding closest ellipse to a closed curve

Tags: python

I have an array of points described by their `x,y` coordinates that represents an isophote. It was determined as a contour of the image. It's a closed curve.

I need to find the closest ellipse to further calculate how different from that ellipse my isophote is. I have no idea where to start.

Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You might find this blog post useful: https://scipython.com/blog/direct-linear-least-squares-fitting-of-an-ellipse/

Answer (score 1):

Finding the "best fit" ellipse for a set of points is a common problem in computer vision and image processing. The general approach uses a method such as least squares to minimize the distance between the points and the ellipse.

Here's a simple way to do it in Python using the `matplotlib.patches`, `matplotlib.transforms`, and `scipy.spatial.distance` libraries:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

# Your points
points = np.random.rand(100, 2)

# Calculate the centroid
centroid = points.mean(axis=0)

# Calculate the distances from the centroid to the points
distances = cdist(points, [centroid])

# Calculate the major and minor axes
major_axis = 2 * distances.max()
minor_axis = 2 * distances.min()

# Create the ellipse
ellipse = Ellipse(xy=centroid, width=major_axis, height=minor_axis, edgecolor='r', fc='None', lw=2)

# Plot the points and the ellipse
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1])
ax.add_patch(ellipse)
plt.show()
```

This code calculates the centroid of the points, then calculates the distances from the centroid to each point. The major axis of the ellipse is twice the maximum distance, and the minor axis is twice the minimum distance. The `Ellipse` function from `matplotlib.patches` is used to create the ellipse, which is then plotted with the points.

Note that this is a very simple approach and may not give the best fit if your points are not distributed evenly around the centroid. A more sophisticated approach would involve using a method such as least squares to find the ellipse that minimizes the total distance to the points. This is a more complex problem and may require a numerical optimization library such as `scipy.optimize`.

Also, please note that this solution is for Python, as the original question was tagged with Python. If you need a solution in a different programming language, please specify the language.

Comment: This code assumes that the major axis of the best-fit ellipse is parallel to the Cartesian x-axis, and the minor axis is parallel to the y-axis. That's not in general true.

Comment: It's also going to perform poorly if the points aren't evenly distributed around the ellipse - that'll cause the centroid to be a bad estimator for the ellipse center.

Comment: @slothrop, As I said, it is a straightforward approach and may not give the best fit. But it is a point to start. According to the question, it is only a direction to think. I assumed a simple system based on whatever data that question gave me. That's all.